# var line extend right but cut off on candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I created a intraday fibonnaci but just stuck on the var line as I'm new to using var line and have been using plot instead.

I'm trying to get the line to cut off at the candle and only extend when a new candle is from, I am using extend to right at the moment which gives me the below result

[Extend Right][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VggLQ.png

Without extend right, it looks like this

[no extend right][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt3jf.png

Is there a way for the line to create itself and stop at the last candle and update once a new candle is form?

```
//@version=5

indicator(title='Auto Intraday Fibonnaci', overlay=true)

line_width = input.int(title="Line Width", defval=2, minval=1, maxval=100)

Fhigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)
Flow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low)

F0 = Flow
F236 = (Fhigh - Flow) * 0.236 + Flow
F382 = (Fhigh - Flow) * 0.382 + Flow
F500 = (Fhigh - Flow) * 0.500 + Flow
F618 = (Fhigh - Flow) * 0.618 + Flow
F786 = (Fhigh - Flow) * 0.786 + Flow
F1000 = (Fhigh - Flow) * 1.000 + Flow

f_newLine(_color) => line.new(na, na, na, na, xloc.bar_time, extend.right, color=_color, width=line_width)

f_moveLine(_line, _x, _y) =>
    line.set_xy1(_line, _x,   _y)
    line.set_xy2(_line, _x+1, _y)

var line    line_0 = f_newLine(color.gray)
var line    line_236 = f_newLine(color.gray)
var line    line_382 = f_newLine(color.gray)
var line    line_500 = f_newLine(color.orange)
var line    line_618 = f_newLine(color.orange)
var line    line_786 = f_newLine(color.gray)
var line    line_1000 = f_newLine(color.gray)

[t0,t236,t382,t500,t618,t786,t1000,dt] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D", [F0,F236,F382,F500,F618,F786,F1000,time], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

if barstate.islast
    f_moveLine(line_0, dt, t0)
    f_moveLine(line_236, dt, t236)
    f_moveLine(line_382, dt, t382)
    f_moveLine(line_500, dt, t500)
    f_moveLine(line_618, dt, t618)
    f_moveLine(line_786, dt, t786)
    f_moveLine(line_1000, dt, t1000)

plotshape(F0 ? F0 : na, style=shape.circle, location=location.absolute, color=color.rgb(120, 123, 134, 100), textcolor=color.new(color.gray, 0), show_last=1, text='0.000', offset=5)
plotshape(F236 ? F236 : na, style=shape.circle, location=location.absolute, color=color.rgb(120, 123, 134, 100), textcolor=color.new(color.gray, 0), show_last=1, text='0.236', offset=5)
plotshape(F382 ? F382 : na, style=shape.circle, location=location.absolute, color=color.rgb(120, 123, 134, 100), textcolor=color.new(color.gray, 0), show_last=1, text='0.382', offset=5)
plotshape(F500 ? F500 : na, style=shape.circle, location=location.absolute, color=color.rgb(255, 235, 59, 100), textcolor=color.new(color.orange, 0), show_last=1, text='0.500', offset=5)
plotshape(F618 ? F618 : na, style=shape.circle, location=location.absolute, color=color.rgb(255, 235, 59, 100), textcolor=color.new(color.orange, 0), show_last=1, text='0.618', offset=5)
plotshape(F786 ? F786 : na, style=shape.circle, location=location.absolute, color=color.rgb(120, 123, 134, 100), textcolor=color.new(color.gray, 0), show_last=1, text='0.786', offset=5)
plotshape(F1000 ? F1000 : na, style=shape.circle, location=location.absolute, color=color.rgb(120, 123, 134, 100), textcolor=color.new(color.gray, 0), show_last=1, text='1.000', offset=5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using `chart.right_visible_bar_time`. I updated the following line of your code and it seems to be working as you desire now.

```
f_moveLine(_line, _x, _y) =>
    line.set_xy1(_line, _x,   _y)
    line.set_xy2(_line, chart.right_visible_bar_time, _y)
```